# Is there a TS library to format numbers in parts with internationalization and abbreviations (React Native usage)?

Tags: react-native, format, internationalization, number-formatting, intl

I am looking for a lib to format currencies and numbers with internationalization, abbreviations (e.g. k, M, G, T for metric and M, B, T for currencies), with and also the ability to return all the parts of the formatted value such as done by the formatToParts method of the Intl namespace

Exemple of what I would like :

```
lib.format(1000000, {locale: 'fr', abbreviate: true, decimals: 2, currency: 'usd'}) 
> {value: 1.00, abbreviation: 'M', currencySign: '$ }
```

My problem with Intl is that it doesnt work on Android, because the formatToParts method 'does not exist'

Comment: How about [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)?

Comment: It's not powerful enough, I don't want to define by hand the internationalization and I'm not sure it can return parts of the formatting